# tfjs predict with sliding window

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, keras, sliding-window, tensorflow.js

Hello I've created and trained detection system in keras to detect and classify analog numbers on gauge meters. System is based on two neural conv nets. First one detects if there is a number and if so, second net tells me what number it is. Since I know where are numbers placed vertically, process of searching for a number is solved by sliding window from left to right.

Because I'm doing a Cordova hybrid application, these neural nets are ported to tensorflow.js. This solution works surprisingly well, but it's very slow. On my pc and Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact it's about 12 seconds.

```
const CROP_DIMENSION = 64


export default class NumberDetector {

    windowWidth = 7
    windowMoveBy = 1
    windowHeight = 80
    isNumberModel = null
    numberClassifyModel = null
    isInitialized = false
    localeServerUrl = null
    async run (image) {
        if (!this.isInitialized) {
            throw new OCRNotInitializedError()
        }
        /* sliding window */
        let finalNumber = ''
        let currentSegmentNumbers = []
        let currentNumber
        let timestampStart = new Date()
        for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(100 / this.windowMoveBy); i++) {
            let x1 = i * this.byPercentage(image.width, this.windowMoveBy)
            // let x2 = x1 + this.byPercentage(image.width, this.windowWidth)
            let x2 = this.byPercentage(image.width, this.windowWidth)
            let y1 = this.byPercentage(image.height, 100 - this.windowHeight)
            let y2 = this.byPercentage(image.height, this.windowHeight)
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
            canvas.width = CROP_DIMENSION
            canvas.height = CROP_DIMENSION
            let context = canvas.getContext('2d')
            context.drawImage(image, x1, y1, x2, y2, 0, 0, CROP_DIMENSION, CROP_DIMENSION)
            let imageArray = context.getImageData(0, 0, CROP_DIMENSION, CROP_DIMENSION).data
            let imageArrayGray = this.convertImageArrayToGray(imageArray)
            let grayImage = this.convertGrayImageArrayToImage(imageArrayGray)
            grayImage = tf.expandDims(grayImage, 0)
            if (await this.checkIfNumber(grayImage)) {
                window.document.body.appendChild(canvas)
                currentNumber = await this.classifyNumber(grayImage)
                console.log(currentNumber)
                currentSegmentNumbers.push(currentNumber)
            } else {
                console.log('x')
                if (currentSegmentNumbers.length) {
                    finalNumber += this.getMostOccurrenceNumber(currentSegmentNumbers)
                }
                currentSegmentNumbers = []
            }
        }
        let timestampEnd = new Date()
        console.log('finalNumber', finalNumber, timestampEnd - timestampStart)
        return finalNumber
    }
    init (localeServerUrl) {
        this.localeServerUrl = localeServerUrl
        let promises = []
        promises.push(this.loadIsNumberModel())
        promises.push(this.loadNumberClassifyModel())
        return Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => {
                this.isInitialized = true
            })
    }
    loadNumberClassifyModel () {
        let url = 'models/numbers/model.json'
        if (this.localeServerUrl) {
            url = this.localeServerUrl + '/' + url
        }
        return tf.loadModel(url)
            .then((model) => {
                this.numberClassifyModel = model
            })
    }
    loadIsNumberModel () {
        let url = 'models/yon/model.json'
        if (this.localeServerUrl) {
            url = this.localeServerUrl + '/' + url
        }
        return tf.loadModel(url)
            .then((model) => {
                this.isNumberModel = model
            })
    }
    convertImageArrayToGray (imageArray) {
        /*
         * Canvas is RGBA
         * Human can see ~30% of red, ~60% green and ~10% blue
         * Do weighted average of RGB channels and drop alpha channel
         */
        let grayScaleArray = []
        let grayValue
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i += 4) {
            // grayValue = (imageArray[i] * 0.3) + (imageArray[i + 1] * 0.6) + (imageArray[i + 2] * 0.1)
            grayValue = (imageArray[i] * 0.299) + (imageArray[i + 1] * 0.587) + (imageArray[i + 2] * 0.114)
            grayScaleArray.push(grayValue)
        }
        return grayScaleArray
    }
    convertGrayImageArrayToImage (imageArray) {
        /**
         * Make array[64,64,1] (width, height, color channel)
         * Read array by rows and map them to 2D
         */
        let image = new Array(CROP_DIMENSION).fill(0).map(x => Array(CROP_DIMENSION).fill(0).map(x => Array(1).fill(0)))
        let row = 0
        let column = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
            image[row][column][0] = imageArray[i] / 255.0
            if (column >= (CROP_DIMENSION - 1)) {
                row++
                column = 0
            } else {
                column++
            }
        }
        return image
    }
    async checkIfNumber (croppedFloatArray) {
        let result = this.isNumberModel.predict(croppedFloatArray)
        return result.data()
            .then((data) => {
                return parseInt(this.getIndexWithMaxValue(data))
            })
    }
    async classifyNumber (croppedFloatArray) {
        let result = this.numberClassifyModel.predict(croppedFloatArray)
        return result.data()
            .then((data) => {
                return this.getIndexWithMaxValue(data)
            })
    }
    getMostOccurrenceNumber (numbers) {
        let occurrenceNumbers = {}
        for (let number of numbers) {
            if (!occurrenceNumbers[number]) {
                occurrenceNumbers[number] = 0
            }
            occurrenceNumbers[number]++
        }
        let keys = Object.keys(occurrenceNumbers)
        let max = -1
        let maxKey = -1
        let current
        for (let key of keys) {
            current = occurrenceNumbers[key]
            if (current > max) {
                max = current
                maxKey = key
            }
        }
        return maxKey
    }
    byPercentage (size, percentage) {
        return parseInt(size / 100 * percentage)
    }
    getIndexWithMaxValue (array) {
        let topVal = 0
        let indexOfTopVal = 0
        for (let index in array) {
            if (array[index] > topVal) {
                topVal = array[index]
                indexOfTopVal = index
            }
        }
        return indexOfTopVal
    }
}
```

I think that problem lies in repeated calculating of feature map. I need to somehow give tensorflow the whole image and tell it: calculate feature map and then apply sliding window. Current solution generates output in 12 seconds. I really have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please provide any example?

Comment: You mentioned that you are running this in Cordova and the model runs very slowly. What is the device type? Can you use `tf.getBackend()` to find out what backend TensorFlow.js is using? If it's not "webgl", then it means the computation is happening on the CPU without acceleration, which could be the reason for the slowness.

Comment: It's Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact. It has webgl2 and runs on webgl, I am sure. I reduced both nets to inputs 32x32 and lowered number of neurons in hidden layers. Precision is same and right now I get the result in ~1,5s on mobile device. But still, I am curious. Is there any way to compute whole image and after that apply this sliding window? There are huuuuge overlaps between windows. I am probably missing come concept.